# Component doesn't update after changes in URL in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an Angular app with user page component that displays user data. Everything works fine except one thing. When I'm currently on some other user and pressing `"My profile"` button that redirects me to my page (registered user) using Angular RouterLink nothong changes except url in browser, if it was `/user/14` it becomes `/user/6` but the data in component doesn't change at all before I manually reload the page. I'm using 2 components in layout - first is the navbar component where `"My profile"` button is situated and second is user component where actual userdata is being displayed. Here is relevant HTML for navbar component:

```
<li class="nav-item sub">
  <a class="nav-link unselectable" routerLink="/user/{{user.id}}" routerLinkActive="nav-link-active"> 
    <span class="icon icon-profile"></span> my profile
  </a>
</li>
```

TS component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, RouterLinkActive, RouterLink } from '@angular/router';

import { User } from '@models/user.model';
import { AuthenticationService } from '@services/auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.css']
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  user: User;

  constructor(private router: Router, private auth_service: AuthenticationService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.dropdown = false;
    // console.log('init_step');
    this.subscr = this.auth_service.currentUser;
    this.auth_service.getUser().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.user = data;
      });
  }

  gt_myprofile() {
    let id = this.auth_service.currentUserValue.id
    this.router.navigate([`/user/${id}`]);
    this.auth_service.getUser().subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.user = data;
      });
  }

}
```

And HTML for user component:

```
<div class="container" id="layout">
  <div class="row justify-content">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-4 no-gutters">
      <app-entity-card-user [user]='user'></app-entity-card-user>
      <!--send/follow-->
      <!--stats-->
      <div class="btn-group container" role="group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-group-element" (click)="userFollowers()">
          <p class="btn-group-element-count">
            {{user.followers_count}}
          </p>
          <p class="btn-group-element-name">
            Followers
          </p>
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-group-element" (click)="userFollowing()">
          <p class="btn-group-element-count">
            {{user.following_count}}
          </p>
          <p class="btn-group-element-name">
            Followings
          </p>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-5 no-gutters">
      <!--posting form-->
      <app-post-form *ngIf="owner"></app-post-form>
      <!--switcher-->
      <app-profile-wall [user]="user"></app-profile-wall>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5 col-lg-3 no-gutters">
      <app-speciality [user]="user"></app-speciality>
      <app-skills [user]="user"></app-skills>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And TS part:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

import { User } from '@models/user.model';
import { AuthenticationService } from '@services/auth.service';
import { FollowersService } from '@services/followers.service';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  user;
  id;
  followers;
  isFollowing: boolean;
  originUser: boolean = false;
  owner;

  constructor(
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private followersService: FollowersService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
    if (this.id == JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser')).id) {
      this.originUser = true;
    } else { console.log('false')}
    this.authenticationService.getSpecUser(this.id).subscribe(
      ((info) => {
        this.user = info;
        if (this.user.id === this.authenticationService.currentUserValue.id){
          this.owner = true;
        } else {
          this.owner = false;
        }
        this.followersService.getFollowing().subscribe(
          data => {
            this.followers = data;
            this.isFollowing = this.followers.some(d => d.id == this.user.id);
          }
        );
      })
    );
  }
}
```

I'm aware that I should use onDestroy or onChange hooks here to achieve result that I need, but after several attempts nothing changed. I've also tried to pass `user` as input from navbar but it didn't help either. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you show router path code in app.module

Comment: `path: 'user/:id', component: UserComponent` in app-routing.module It works fine, because when I reload page data appears and also url in browser changes

Comment: Are you not getting any errors in the console?

Comment: You are trying to redirect to different component or just changing the `id`

Comment: I'm not getting any errors in console and I'm not trying to redirect to another component, just change the `id`, my goal is to retrieve new data and update page without reloading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are accessing the snapshot, so the id will not update.

If you subscribe to the `paramMap` of the activatedRoute, the id will change:

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(params => {
  this.id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
  // do the rest here...
});
```

[Example StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkgaq5)